# Getting assembly version info from static class throws a stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have struggled with this for a bit, and I have a feeling I am very close. In a .NET MVC web application I have used to have assemblyinfo information displayed in the front end without issue. In a bit of optimization I wanted to move that code out to a general purpose helper class.
For ease of use I have made it a static class, but I have hit several snags in the process. But now it throws a System.StackOverflowException when I try to use it, sadly. Here is the code:

```
public static class VersionInformationHelper
{
    public static string GetVersionNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetVersionNumber.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()))
            {
                return "v" + GetVersionNumber.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remark>
    /// This doesnt exactly return the commit hash so to speak. Well it does, but Teamcity is set to enter the corresponding commit hash information when building, 
    /// into productversion in "AssemblyInfo.cs". It could be any string really. But we assume that a commit hash will always be in that location.
    /// It's "Assembly informational version" in the assemblyinfo patcher build feature in teamcity.
    /// </remark>
    public static string GetCommitHash
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(GetVersionNumber.GetType().Assembly.Location).ProductVersion))
            {
                return System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(GetVersionNumber.GetType().Assembly.Location).ProductVersion;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetBuildDate
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}", System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(GetVersionNumber.GetType().Assembly.Location));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Fixed code based on feedback (GetVersionNumber and GetCommitHash" has been changed):

```
public static class VersionInformationHelper
{
    public static string GetVersionNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()))
            {
                return "v" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remark>
    /// This doesnt exactly return the commit hash so to speak. Well it does, but Teamcity is set to enter the corresponding commit hash information when building, 
    /// into productversion in "AssemblyInfo.cs". It could be any string really. But we assume that a commit hash will always be in that location.
    /// It's "Assembly informational version" in the assemblyinfo patcher build feature in teamcity.
    /// </remark>
    public static string GetCommitHash
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion))
            {
                return System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetBuildDate
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}", System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(GetVersionNumber.GetType().Assembly.Location));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: side note: methods in property form are a bad idea as generally speaking they don't get optimised; best to keep properties as properties and if it's a method it should be a method

Comment: Good information, I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading `GetVersionNumber` from the getter of same `GetVersionNumber` (twice). This will loop infinitely (or until a stack overflow occurs).

You probably need to change the two occurences with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()` or another method to get the version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, following your tips I made some modifications and it seems to be working :) I have updated my original post with the fixed code.